# How to call from code like that button clicked?

Tags: java, swing, action, jbutton, actionlistener

I have in code implement `ActionListener` for `JToggleButton`. How to call from code like that button clicked? (similar in javascript from code I can do `$('button').click();`)
How to do this in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `JButton` we have `button.doClick()`, inherited from `AbstractButton`. So, we should have `doClick()` for `JToggleButton()` as well, since that is also derived from `AbstractButton`.

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful... http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/swingevents/

Answer (score 1):

you have to reads basic tutorial for [JButton](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [ActionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) , examples for that [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Button.htm) and [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/0080__ActionListener.htm)